# Automatic JOIN generation in Doctrine 2

Tags: join, doctrine-orm

Does Doctrine 2 support automatic JOIN generation? That is, assuming I have a Seller entity which is associated with some Product entities, each of which have a Category, doing something like

```
$sellers = $entityManager->getRepository('Foo\Bar\Seller')->findBy(array('country' => 'US'), array('populate' => array('Product', 'Product.Category')));
foreach ($sellers as $seller) {
    doStuffWith($seller->product->category);
}
```

and the whole thing would take a single query because Doctrine would join the product and category tables to the seller table and use the results to pre-populate the associations. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to automatically do a JOIN:

- Use eager fetching
- Use DQL

Eager fetching means that whenever the main entity is fetched, Doctrine 2 will automatically also fetch any relations which are marked as "eager". This is done by using the `fetch` attribute in mappings (see [Manual: ManyToOne](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=eager#manytoone))

With DQL, you would need to write a query which fetches both the main entity and the related entity/entities:

`SELECT m, r FROM My\MainEntity m LEFT JOIN m.relatedEntity r`

The benefit of eager fetching vs DQL is that with eager fetches, you will get the feature essentially automatically. However, the downside of eager fetching is that if you don't actually use the related entities, you may incur a performance penalty. With DQL, you always have control over what you fetch and when.

Comment: DQL is not what I would call automatic. Eager fetching would be nice (and it seems to be possible to [dynamically enable it](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql)), but as far as I understand, it will still generate a bunch of queries: instead of a JOIN, it will do something like `SELECT * FROM sellers`, `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (...)`˙, `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id IN (...)` which is still a fair bit slower. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: An eager fetch should do a JOIN as far as I know. I don't really see why it would use an IN query like that

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution (fetch=“EAGER” on the relationship) reduced the number of queries from 111 to 9 on one of my pages! Awesome solution. Never heard about.

Comment: Eager fetching will execute the multiple queries required, to several tables, all together instead that when requesting items from an association (lazy-load). However Doctrine will **not** JOIN your entities in a single query because each query should return a set of mapped objects of the same type. From what I know Doctrine doesn't fetch multiple types in a single query; this might be possible with an ad-hoc mapper (mapping fields from multiple tables toward multiple entity types).

Answer (score 0):

From [Doctrine Query Language documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

> A common mistake for beginners is to mistake DQL for being just some form of SQL and therefore trying to use table names and column names or join arbitrary tables together in a query. You need to think about DQL as a query language for your object model, not for your relational schema.

If you want to use **objects** (entities), each with its own repository, you should not think in terms of SQL (or `JOIN`ing tables), because a repository and **a DQL query will always return only a single type of object**.
The ORM purpose is to allow you to think as objects (rather than tables), without thinking in terms of technical implementation of the persistence layer: think of Associations, not of `join`s; necessary SQL-queries get executed automatically as-needed & under-the-hood without thinking too much about premature optimization (Doctrine is not ideal for performances; and however sometimes many queries can be faster than a big single joined query).

If you fetch joined-data from multiple SQL tables (so multiple types) then your query result records don't represent anymore each a single/unique object but rather each record is a mashup of data from multiple tables and concerning multiple models.

What entity should an ORM map, if you make a query resulting in `SELECT seller.*, product.name, product.price, category.name FROM ..`?
Just map to a *Seller*? A *Product* with missing properties?
What single entity should be mapped from each record of a SQL result like:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| seller.id | seller.name |  product.name   | product.price |  category.name  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|        42 | Alan Smith  | Apple MacBook   | 1500$         | Computer&Mobile |
|        42 | Alan Smith  | Apple MacBook   | 1850$         | Computer&Mobile |
|        42 | Alan Smith  | Dell XPS        | 1500$         | Computer&Mobile |
|        34 | Jane Foley  | Clarinet Selmer | 1720$         | Music           |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

?

The ORM cannot guess!

Hence you'll need a custom mapper for telling Doctrine how to build an entity object (model) out of a SQL row with mixed data.
Take a look at the [Native SQL documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html) for how to build your own `ResultSetMapping`.